# Drupal gives error while add content or edit node

Tags: 7, theming

Hi all i am facing this error when try to edit node or add content

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =&gt; node [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =&gt; %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file). [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =&gt; a:6:{s:5:&quot;%type&quot;;s:12:&quot;PDOException&quot;;s:8:&quot;!message&quot;;s:238:&quot;SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {variable} variable WHERE ( (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&amp;gt; drupal_http_request_fails ) &quot;;s:9:&quot;%function&quot;;s:14:&quot;variable_set()&quot;;s:5:&quot;%file&quot;;s:74:&quot;/home/apetrdo6/public_html/Development/InfinityPups/includes/bootstrap.inc&quot;;s:5:&quot;%line&quot;;i:991;s:14:&quot;severity_level&quot;;i:3;} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =&gt; 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =&gt; [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =&gt; http://apetrailportfolio.com/Development/InfinityPups/node/add/dogs [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =&gt; http://apetrailportfolio.com/Development/InfinityPups/node/add/dogs [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =&gt; 103.63.25.150 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] =&gt; 1473159652 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 160 of /home/apetrdo6/public_html/Development/InfinityPups/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {variable} variable WHERE ( (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; drupal_css_cache_files ) in variable_set() (line 991 of /home/apetrdo6/public_html/Development/InfinityPups/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: UPDATE {users} SET access=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE (uid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1473159609 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1 ) in _drupal_session_write() (line 219 of /home/apetrdo6/public_html/Development/InfinityPups/includes/session.inc).

Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 80080962057cea1b962fce6.76953018 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of /home/apetrdo6/public_html/Development/InfinityPups/includes/lock.inc).
```

Comment: Check your error log tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log. You may find a hint.

Comment: Check whether the mysql server works fine. The server might be killed by mistake. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to solve is to increase "max_allowed_packet" .

> ```
>     Go to xampp\mysql\bin
>     Open my.ini
>     Change "max_allowed_packet" from "1m" to "16m"
>     Save my.ini
>     Now restart MySql through the XAMPP control panel.
> ```

Or

settings.php

```
ini_set('max_allowed_packet', '1024M');
```

Comment: Well currently i am working on live server where i set value

Comment: current  my 
PHP memory limit 128M

Comment: memory_limit is separate from max_allowed_packet.

Comment: You need to change on server my.ini file or you can make the changes on setting.php file of drupal.

Comment: still same error